# JSX Bootstrap unterminated

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with react, and the compiler is failing on grounds that there is unterminated JSX contents. I've been through it a dozen times, and whichever way the ternary results, I don't see any unclosed tags. I'm new to react, so I suppose something else must be wrong. To cut down on code, I've only included the return():

```
<div className="container-fluid">

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <SearchBar />
          </div>
        </div>


    {this.state.results ? (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-6 offset-md-3">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                                        <InputRange
                                        maxValue={this.state.maxPrice}
                                        minValue={this.state.minPrice}
                                        value={this.state.priceRange}
                                        formatLabel={x => {
                                        return `£${x}`;
                                        }}
                                        onChange={value => this.setState({ priceRange: value })}
                                        />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                                            Selection: {visibleResults.length}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div>
                </div>

                    <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-6 offset-md-3">
                                 {visibleResults.map((item, index) => (
                                    <Link to={`/listing/${item.id}`}>
                                    <SearchResult result={item} key={index} />
                                    </Link>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        ) : (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
                    <h1>LOADING...</h1>
                </div>
        </div>
    )}

    </div>
)
```

Comment: In general, I find that JSX can get extremely complicated if you use it as literals in very complicated expressions. It might help to clarify things if you create some functions (or other components!) which encapsulate the more complicated logic you've got going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the div here:

```
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                                        Selection: {visibleResults.length}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div> // This should be </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Great catch, thank you. Quick question - I have eslint installed, with the airbnb default config. I would have expected it to catch that... Have I configured it wrongly, or am I expecting too much?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's been awhile since I've used ESLint on its own. I've been using Prettier with ESLint and I feel like it's really helped cut down on errors and improve formatting consistency: https://prettier.io/docs/en/eslint.html